# Re-install the App Store application on OS X 10.6.8

Tags: snow-leopard, mac-appstore

I deleted the App Store application with AppCleaner some months ago, after ongoing problems with a freezing Finder. Now I would like to reinstall, but I cannot find a way. The 10.6.6 combo updater of course will not do the job because it needs an older OS X incarnation and I'm running 10.6.8.

Comment: Have you tried the 10.6.8 combo updater?

Comment: you could try to get the updater files and extract `App Store.app`

Comment: Restore if from your normal backup?

Answer (score 2):

### [Download and re-install the Mac OS X 10.6.8 Update Combo v1.1.](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1399)

at the link above.

Answer (score 0):

This guy extracted the App http://www.qubesys.com/reinstall-mac-app-store/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to trust an Internet version of the app, you can always reinstall from your Snow Leopard disc / restore media and run the combo updater of your choice. Any combo updater [10.6.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fkb%2FDL1349&answerid=16777222&src=support_site.downloads.search), [10.6.7](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fkb%2FDL1361&answerid=16777216&src=support_site.downloads.search) or [10.6.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=answerlink&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.apple.com%2Fkb%2FDL1399&answerid=16777220&src=support_site.downloads.search) will have the App Store on it.

Also, your backup should have a copy of the app.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with downloading the app that someone has extracted is that it is coded with his Apple ID.  At this time I am unable to change the ID in the program to allow me to use it.  Better choice is to go with re-installing the update.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not formatted like a normal forum. This "answer" seems like it should be a comment on RobZolkos's answer. If it is, please make a comment and delete this answer. If you intended this to be an answer in its own right, please flesh it out with some more detail.