# Reinstall Mac App Store on Mac OS 10.7?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-appstore, mac-mini

I accidentally removed the Mac App from my Mac Mini while removing the iTunes 10.5 Beta. How can I reinstall the Mac App Store?

Comment: For a similar problem with 10.6.8, see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17687/re-install-the-app-store-application-on-osx-10-6-8

Comment: Unfortunately patrix I can't use the 10.6.8 update combo to fix this :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the .app file off my machine: http://cl.ly/0f293H081S2e1Y2B3f1r

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I'm restoring my machine to see if that will work from a Time Machine backup right now. But if that doesn't work I'll try your copy. I'll get back to you if everything works out okay.

Comment: Also, before I started the restore, the Mac App Store blank icon was still in my apps folder and it wouldn't let me delete it.

Comment: I can confirm that the .app file posted by XAleXOwnZX worked. Thanks very much!

Comment: @donturner hehehe you just installed malware! Just kidding, enjoy :p glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

oh, good question. Maybe install a basic Lion system onto an external HD and copy the app from there? Or you don't have a backup like Time Machine or anything similar, do you?

Maybe someone with an identical version of the OS can zip the file and send it to you.

I think that whatever way you wanna do it, copying the app from one Mac to another should work. As long as the OS versions match of course...

Comment: Okay, sweet. I just did a backup with Time Machine a few hours ago. I'll try to get ahold of a friend who has 10.7.2 that can copy it over for me. Also I think I can reinstall it from the Lion Recovery, but i'm not sure. That's what they seem to be telling me on the Apple Discussions board https://discussions.apple.com/message/16715675#16715675